# Splitting polygons layer by using line layer not working in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I am using qgis in project and trying to split polygons layer by using a line layer. 
I used the the splite tool in qgis as explained in many posts.
The output after splitting the polygon layer is deleting all the left side polygons from the  splitter and kept the polygons at the right side. One side kept and the other side disappeared.

How to keep both polygons sides from the line splitter?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please click 'edit' and provide some more information - in particular, what is the 'splite' tool, and please provide a link to one of the other posts! Providing a link to example data would be useful as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SAGA Polygon-line intersection algorithm from the Processing Toolbox to achieve this.
To run the algorithm navigate from the Processing top menu of QGIS.
**Processing** -> **Toolbox** this should open the Processing Toolbox window/view. Go to the SAGA section Shapes - Polygons Polygon-line intersection follow the Parameters input and it should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, I found the problem was because the line splitter I am using was not extending all the polygons, after I edited it and extend it , the sppliting tool was warking perfectly

Thanks